# How should DataTables be assigned to DataSets?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

I have one DataSet called `DataSet1.xsd`

In that particular DataSet, I have all the DataTables related to my program. For example:

1. dtTable1_**a**
2. dtTable2_**a**
3. dtTable3_**a**
4. dtTable4_**b**
5. dtTable5_**b**
6. dtTable6_**c**

For the record, I did not actually name these tables like this. This is just to show that the DataTable with `a` is considered to contain everything related to Persons. As such, the Datatable with `b` contains everything for the Clients... And so on.

Is it better practice to split those DataTables into different DataSets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a relationship between the tables contained in the DataSet then they need to be in a DataSet with the appropriate constraints, if not then they should be in separate DataSets or possibly just DataTables on their own.